# OSM in online mode

Tags: openstreetmap

Started using OSM in online mode

Thanks

Comment: “*I ran the tile downloader for a week*”

uuuh. this is bad. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Bulk_Downloading

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. OSM runs on funded servers and bulk downloading of tiles is forbidden according to the [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) as already explained by tyr.

Instead, you can [render your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). Also note that this will require some amount of storage. For storing all "interesting" tiles you will need around [1300GB](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Disk_Usage).

And what is your ultimate goal?